# Android: Intent for when the SD card is TRULY mounted and readable

Tags: android, android-intent, sd-card, mount

I have the following setup:

SD card Mount Receiver (MountReceiver.java)

```
public IntentFilter getIntentFilter() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("file");
    return intentFilter;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(action)) {
        setMounted(true);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.equals(action)) {
        setMounted(false);
    }
}

private void setMounted(boolean isMounted) {
    if (isMounted) {
        doPerformQuery();
    }
}
```

And when I register the receiver, I do:

```
registerReceiver(mountInstance, mountInstance.getIntentFilter());
```

Everything is fine and dandy and working as expected. I can unmount and remount my SD card and my setMounted method is fired as appropriate. The problem I have is, is that my doPerformQuery() method returns 0 results after the SD card is mounted. If I change the code to:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
doPerformQuery();
```

Then it will work, occasionally. This gives the SD card 5 seconds to finish "preparing". I want to know when the SD card has finished preparing and can be read. Currently, I'm getting the intent when the SD card is mounted, but it hasn't "prepared" itself yet, so it's not readable. Is there such an intent to register to when the SD card has finished "preparing". On a side note, I say "preparing" because that's what my phone says in the notification bar. I'm not sure if this is standard across all phones as I can't find a single thing about the SD card preparing online.

Comment: @Nick: Could it be that your SD card is being 'scanned' for new media (music etc)? Have you tried checking ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED and the associated intent actions? Just a long shot.

Comment: You may have hit the nail on the head. It is scanning for new music (roughly 1200 songs on my phone). And my query is to grab the songs from the phone. I didn't know of such an intent, but this sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks. I'll play around with this and post my results.

Comment: @Nick: I'd be interested to know if that helped and if waiting on the associated scan finished intent solves the problem.

Comment: @MisterSquonk, thank you for your help! ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED was exactly what I needed. If you want, you can make this an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: And for those who may have this same question. I just added intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED); to my method above. I added another else-if to my onReceive method to check if the action is this new action. And for kicks and giggles I added an additional check to make sure the scanner finished the SD card: if (intent.getDataString().contains(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString())).

Comment: @Nick: Glad I was able to point you in the right direction. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to our comments to your original question...

I think the logic is that when the SD card is dismounted, the content provider for various AV media (videos, music, photos etc) is cleared of anything on the SD card because the system won't know when (if ever) the same SD card will return and if it does whether it will have the same files on it. As a result, a full scan is carried out each time an SD card is installed (resulting in the 'preparing' notification).

So in your case, checking for ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED and most importantly the associated ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED means the AV media content provider will have a current list of everything on the card.

Comment: The second paragraph is exactly why I'm listening for this intent. I need to know what content changed on the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` result ([link to API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29)).

I'm pretty sure you will get `MEDIA_CHECKING` until a few seconds later. If that's correct, you can use a simple `while` loop to check it and proceed when the state changes to `MEDIA_MOUNTED`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting MEDIA_MOUNTED when I use Environment.getExternalStorageState(). But I didn't realize there was a MEDIA_CHECKING state, so I'll do some research on that just to make sure. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Nick not too much help unfortunately. Good luck.

Comment: This always returns internal memory for my device.  How can I get the device's "true" external (removeable) storage state?  How does this work for devices with multiple storage devices?